# Getting Min and Max from array

Tags: java

I am trying to build an array from user input of numbers.  I have been able to calculate everything but min and max.  The code below always comes up with the first number input by user as both the min and max.  Any suggestions on how to fix would be greatly appreciated:

```
   Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
        int num[]=new int[5];
        int average=0;
        int i=0;
        int sum=0;

        for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            num[i]=in.nextInt();
            sum=sum+num[i];
            int min=num[0];
            int max=num[0];
            if (num[i]<min) {
            min=num[i];
            }
            if (num[i]<max) {
            max=num[i];
        }

        average=sum/6;
        System.out.println("Average="+ average);
        System.out.println("Min="+ min);
        System.out.println("Max="+ max);
        System.out.println("Sum="+ sum);
```

Comment: "if (num[i]<max) { max=num[i]; }" must be "if (num[i]>max) { max=num[i]; }" ???

Comment: This code doesn't even compile as `min` and `max` are declared inside the loop and used outside of it.

Comment: Why not input all of the information into the array, then sort it? The ends of your array would be your min and max.

Comment: @SaviourSelf looks like OP is in learning phase, so sorting would be overkill for this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Here's a bit improved one:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
double num[]=new double[5];
double average=0;
int i=0;
double sum=0;

double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;

for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    num[i]=in.nextDouble();
    sum=sum+num[i];
    if (num[i]<min) {
        min=num[i];
    } else if (num[i] > max) {
        max=num[i];
    }
}

average=sum/num.length;
System.out.println(String.format("Average=%.3d", average));
System.out.println(String.format("Min=%.3d", min));
System.out.println(String.format("Max=%.3d", max));
System.out.println(String.format("Sum=%.3d", sum));
```

Also, I replaced ints with doubles, as you wished :)

Comment: `sum` should be double or multiply it by `1.0` when calculating `average` (that also should be `double`). Also, when printing `double` variables, it would be better using `String#format` and `%.3d` to get a meaningful output.

Comment: "`sum` should be double or multiply it by `1.0` when calculating `average`" - huh? I'm casting it to `double` (`(double)sum`), it should be enough :)

Comment: Anyway, you haven't addresed it nor fixed it after comments =\

Comment: Hmmm? I don't understand... :|

Comment: thank you. Also do I need to change int i to double?  I need to learn how to both except double from user and print double.

Comment: You can change `average` variable type to double to get higher precision of the value :) Of course, you'll need to remove the cast to the int: `average=(double)sum/num.length;` instead of `average=(int) ((double)sum/num.length);`.

Comment: got it.  So there is no concept of nextDouble() instead of nextInt() to allow decimal input by user?

Comment: Of course there is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble() What you need to do is only replace `int num[]` with `double num[]`, etc. - I can even edit the answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. I'm not sure if it is correct, but... it should be. If there's some compile errors, warnings or the code doesn't work properly, just write a comment, I'll try to fix it :>

Answer (score 3):

```
        int min=num[0];
        int max=num[0];
```

Move min and max out of the for loop.

```
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

The min and max if blocks should be the other way round.

And the average should be calculated as:

```
    average = sum / num.length;
```

Beware of averages being truncated due to *ints*

Answer (score 2):

Declare min and max out of the scope of loop.

```
 int min =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 int max= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 double average = 0D;
      for(..){

      if (num[i] > max) { // this is the condition you have to put
        max=num[i];
      }
     } 

     average=  ((double)sum/num.length);
     System.out.printf("Average is %.2f \n",average);//to print with 2 decimals
```

Comment: This is not even close to an answer. By the way, if `min` is a lower value than user input, it won't never change.

Comment: Refer to [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862) section 10. Also, it falls in the same problem as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17598719/1065197) (but looks like upvoters doesn't even test the code before voting).

Comment: Your first attempt was just posting code that *could* solve the problem, and no giving any proper explanation. After your edit: 1. `min = num[0];` before the loop that fills the array is like doing `min = 0;`, so if user **never** inputs something below 0, `min` will be `0`. 2. `sum` is `int` and `num.length` is `int`, so the division will be an `int` as well, by declaring `average` as `double` won't solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Error stay here is:

```
 int min=num[0];
 int max=num[0];
```

This code must be outside the loop for{}.

Comment: And you should initialize `min` with a big value and `max` with a low value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int min,max;min=max=min[0];
      for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("enter a number");
                num[i]=in.nextInt();
                sum=sum+num[i];
                if (num[i]<min) {
                min=num[i];
                }
                if (num[i]<max) {
                max=num[i];
            }
```

Apart from this there are lot of other problems in your code

1.Move min and max outside for loop

2.Use Double/Float to store average as using int would result in truncation of result.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the min and max variables before the loop. If you are in the first loop (i=0) you can assign it. Else, you compare it. Something like this :

```
Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    int num[]=new int[5];
    int average=0;
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    int min;
    int max;

    for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        num[i]=in.nextInt();
        sum=sum+num[i];
        if(i==0) {
            min=num[0];
            max=num[0];
        } else {
            if (num[i]<min) {
                min=num[i];
            }
            if (num[i]<max) {
                max=num[i];
            }
        }
    }

    average=sum/6;
    System.out.println("Average="+ average);
    System.out.println("Min="+ min);
    System.out.println("Max="+ max);
    System.out.println("Sum="+ sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort.

```
List<Integer> foo = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7);
Collections.sort(foo);
System.out.println("max=" + foo.get(foo.size()-1));
System.out.println("min=" + foo.get(0));
```

If you include some Apache libraries, you can use their stuff, such as:

```
System.out.println(NumberUtils.max(new int[]{5,6,7}));
```